# Point interpolation in route

Tags: gps, interpolation, coordinates

I have a set of GPS coords with X,Y and Course. I need to interpolate additional points based on the course of each point. It would be a simple line intersection based on lines drawn using the 2 locations and course.

EDIT:
Let me clarify .. i have a set of gps logged points, each with lat/long, heading and speed. I need to interpolate an additional point between each known location based on the 2 known points and there headding. Kind of like dead-reconing but after the fact. It'll be a linear interpolation.. here is an image of said problem [1](http://api.bleepsquare.co.za/problem.png)...

Comment: @Jan de Jager, what GIS software are you using?

Comment: here is a similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/how-to-interpolate-gps-positions-in-postgis

Comment: @artwork21 - no specific GIS software. I'm generating KML data from mass data stored in MongoDB.

Comment: @Nicklas ... uhmmm.. huh?

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm/formula for this solution...

Comment: What about a bezier curve type interpolation?

Comment: So it seems to be a simple linear problem, but how do you take 2 locations with direction and turn it into y=mx+c ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using either the Haversine or Vincenty formula. Please see my answer here: [How to create a point along a line given distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/how-to-create-a-point-along-a-line-given-distance)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried GPSBabel?
http://werc.engr.uaf.edu/~ken/doc/gpsbabel/htmldoc-1.3.5/filter_interpolate.html

```
gpsbabel -i gpx -f track.gpx -x interpolate,time=10 -o gpx -F newtrack.gpx
gpsbabel -i gpx -f track.gpx -x interpolate,distance=1k -o gpx -F newtrack.gpx
```