# Split a Polyline into small segments

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, .net

I am writing an addin, which needs to split a polyline into a number of segments taking the number of segments as an input from user.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`IGeometryBridge2.SplitAtDistances()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/002m/002m000001st000000.htm). Also see the documentation on the equivalent [`IPolycurve2.SplitAtDistances()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/002m/002m0000029q000000.htm) and the singular [`IPolycurve.SplitAtDistance()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/002m/002m000002m7000000.htm) methods for more explanation.

The `IGeometryBridge2` version must be used in .NET.

**Edit:** This code works for me:

```c#
private static IEnumerable<IPolyline> SplitPolylineIntoEqualSegments(IPolyline polyline, int numSegments)
{
    var geombridge = (IGeometryBridge2)new GeometryEnvironmentClass();
    var paths = (IGeometryCollection)polyline;
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.GeometryCount; i++)
    {
        var path = (IPath)paths.get_Geometry(i);
        var distances = new double[Math.Max(1, numSegments - 1)];
        for (int j = 0; j < distances.Length; j++)
        {
            distances[j] = (j + 1.0) / numSegments;
        }
        var polyline2 = PathToPolyline(path);
        geombridge.SplitAtDistances((IPolycurve2)polyline2, ref distances, true, true);
        var splitpaths = (IGeometryCollection)polyline2;
        for (int k = 0; k < splitpaths.GeometryCount; k++)
        {
            var splitpath = (IPath)splitpaths.get_Geometry(k);
            yield return PathToPolyline(splitpath);
        }
    }
}

private static IPolyline PathToPolyline(IPath path)
{
    var polyline = (IPolyline)new PolylineClass();
    var geomcoll = (IGeometryCollection)polyline;
    geomcoll.AddGeometry(path);
    geomcoll.GeometriesChanged();
    return polyline;
}
```

Comment: :: Thanks.. for the Code...
But I am getting an Enumeration of polylines from this, How can I convert this into a Feature layer containing all these Polylines

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AvinashNirankari do you want to create a feature layer that will contain all these polylines?

Comment: @Emi :: Yes...
Actually I want to use InterpolateShape tool on all of these so I need one layer containing all these polylines....

Comment: Do you know [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)? You can work with [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)'s in any way that you need. I purposely made the function generic so you (and other readers) could adapt it to your needs.

Comment: So what is your problem now? creating a polyline fature layer?

Comment: @Emi:: Ican create a polyline feature layer but the problem is I don't know how to insert these Polylines in the feature layer....

Comment: @AvinashNirankari I added an answer.Have a look.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not actually the answer of the actual question. It's the answer of your comment. Because of the code snippet, I wrote it as a answer:

```
void AddFeatures(List<IPolyline> polylines, IFeatureClass featureClass)
{
    if (featureClass == null)
        return;
    foreach (var polyline in polylines)
    {
        IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
        feature.Shape = polyline;

        feature.Store();
    }
    _activeView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: :: The code you have given is not giving any errors but it is not giving the correct results....
It is adding the only the first segment not the whole line....

Comment: Are you sure about all lines are polylines? because it works for me correctly

Comment: check these things at debug mode:
1. count of polylines > 1; 
2. x,y value of the from point and to point of 1st polyline and other polylines are different.

Comment: :: Oh sorry..!! I was doing it the wrong way at first....
It worked...
Thanks a Lot for your help.....