# Extract a point very close to end point of a line in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I want to extract a point (red star below) on a line very close to the end (and/or start) point of that line, but not the end itself, so that it is a point not intersecting an end asset point (black circle). I thought the easiest way to do this would be to shorten the line by a given length (say 1cm), then extract the end points. Is there a tool to do this in ArcGIS? The tool would be something similar to the [snipper](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/3573/shorten-line-by-fixed-distance.html) tool in FME.

[image]

I was looking for a solution that doesn't involve scripting like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26542/get-a-point-on-a-polyline-from-end-points-given-distance-along-poly-line) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could you draw a very small buffer around the end point and then intersect the line with the buffer and extract the point of intersection.

It should sit on the line at the distance drawn with the buffer.

Comment: Nice, simple solution. Just what I was looking for, cheers!