# Add points for every 100 m at polyline (QGIS/Mapinfo)

Tags: qgis, mapinfo

I have a polyline and want to set points for every 100 m. And if possible, with unique values for each point, 100, 200, 300 etc. Can it be done?

The QGIS-plugin, Sextante algoritmes "v.to points" and "v.segment" might just do that, but can figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a point along a line given distance](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/how-to-create-a-point-along-a-line-given-distance)

Comment: and for QGIS, duplicate of [How to create equidistant points in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27102/how-to-create-equidistant-points-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks Curlew and Gene. But haven´t solved. Tried out Nathans python-solution but can´t get a visual of the created points. http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/generating-chainage-distance-nodes-in-qgis/

Comment: Question tagged with MapInfo as well as QGIS so guess that you have MapInfo available to you.  That being the case is this tool any good?  http://www.directionsmag.com/files/view/distmark-51zip/138895

Comment: Ahh, very interesting. Im still without a solution and will try it soon as possibile, and give feedback.

Comment: @Mark - Very good solution. Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question tagged with MapInfo as well as QGIS so guess that you have MapInfo available to you. That being the case is this [tool](http://www.directionsmag.com/files/view/distmark-51zip/138895) of use?

Description from site:

> Designed to place points along a line at a predefined distance. The start line end is indicated by the user with the mouse click, and hence is not restricted to the line direction. The tool can handle line, polyline and multiple section polylines.

Comment: **Works perfect!**

Answer (score 2):

Even better MapInfo tool:

info: 
http://www.routeware.dk/toolbox.php

ToolBox is a collection of MapBasic programs for performing these tasks:

• Add Nodes
 • Convex hull / Rubberband
 • Extended Table Info
 • Locate the nearest object in one table for all objects in another table - Very fast
 • Locate the N nearest objects in one table for all objects in another table - Very fast
 • Location of facilities
 • Map Coloring
 • Minimum spanning tree
 • Remove holes from regions
 • Simplification of polylines/regions. This removes insignificant nodes from objects
 • **Split of (poly)lines at predefined distances, e.g. for every 100 meters.**
• Split multi-section polylines/regions into single sections
 • Triangulation (TIN)
 • Voronoi polygons

direct download:
http://www.routeware.dk/download/toolbox.zip

install it and use first menu option "Add nodes to Line"

Comment: @sys49152 I tried your .mbx and was successful installing it. However, I cannot get to specify the intervals. I drew a 300m line for example and tried to have an interval of 50m, it only gave a start and end node. Is there any way to have it work properly? Would really appreciate your help. I use MapInfo 12.5

Answer (score 1):

Its sound like you are looking for a chainage solution.
How about trying https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/ ?

> This plugin takes line features and creates a new layer of points in
>   provided distances on top of this Lines. Optionally you can set the
>   startpoint (distance from the start of the line) and the endpoint
>   (stop before reaching the end of the line) and automatically label the
>   new points with the distances.

Comment: Good tip, but I think he needs it only for Mapinfo.